# Postgres JSONB Array Query

Tags: jsonb, postgresql-9.4

How can I use the jsonb query functions to get matching TrackingDetails from the whole table, when the jsonb field in my table contains json in this format? For example, I have an order_events table, with a column called event_data, that will contain this json:

```
{
  "Responses": [
    {
      "Response": {
        "TrackingDetails": {
          "IntegrationId": "IntegrationId",
          "MessagePart": 0,
          "MessageTotal": 0,
          "MessageGroupId": "MessageGroupId",
          "SequenceNumber": "SequenceNumber",
          "InterfaceRecordId": "InterfaceRecordId",
          "SalesOrderNumber": "SalesOrderNumber",
          "SalesOrderReference": "SalesOrderReference",
          "DispatchNumber": "DispatchNumber",
          "Courier": "Courier",
          "TrackingNumber": "TrackingNumber",
          "TrackingUrl": "TrackingUrl"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the TrackingDeatils as a Json node, by TrackingNumber, across all rows in the table. It would include multiple rows matched. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the expected output for that JSON value? Do you need that for a specific row in the table or for multiple rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, I added clarifying text to my post.